# spatie error while publishing the migration file

Tags: laravel

```
I have just install laravel 5.4 & using xampp server
facing issue in spatie. after installing by 'composer require         spatie/laravel-permission'

adding Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class, to service             providers, in config/app.php

next when i use this command  
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider" --tag="m
```

igrations", 
    I receive this error as below

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\laravel\vendor\laravel\frame
```

work\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 1041

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] 
Call to a member function connection() on null
```

Answer (score 0):

after installing the package make sure you have included the service provider in config/app.php providers array then run the following command

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by placing Spatie's service provider after the database service provider.

---

In config/apps.php, in the providers array, place

```
 Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
```

anywhere **after** the line:

```
Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
```

and rerun the publish command again. I'm not sure why though.